# Is there a clean way to use ORDER BY inside an Arel NamedFunction Node?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, arel

I'm using ActiveRecord 4.2 / Arel 6.0 / Postgres and have the following inputs:

- An `Arel::Attributes::Attribute` from an `Arel::Table` (`column`)
- Several `Arel::Nodes::Ordering` nodes (`orders`)

I want to build an `Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction` with an aggregate function that includes the column specified by the `Attribute` and is ordered by the `Ordering` nodes.

The resulting SQL could look something like:

```
array_agg("posts"."id" ORDER BY "posts"."published_at" DESC)
```

My current solution is to first build an `Arel::Nodes::SelectStatement`, add the column and orders to it, convert it to SQL, strip the leading `SELECT` keyword, wrap it in an `Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral` and pass that to the `NamedFunction` node:

```
select = Arel::Nodes::SelectStatement.new
select.cores.last.projections << column
select.orders = orders

sql = select.to_sql.sub(/^SELECT /, '')
literal = Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new(sql)

array_agg = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('array_agg', [literal])
```

Obviously, this is a huge hack.

Keeping the `ORDER BY` outside the aggregate function is not an option, because it would conflict with the `GROUP BY` used to aggregate.

So is there a cleaner way to achieve this without abusing `SelectStatement` / `SelectManager`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use an `Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation` to build the "ORDER BY" node and an `Arel::Nodes::StringJoin` to build a comma separated list of `Arel::Nodes::Ordering`:

```
ordering = Arel::Nodes::StringJoin.new(orders)
order_by = Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('ORDER BY', column, ordering)
array_agg = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('array_agg', [order_by])
```

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if this works for you but I found this to be a clean way to order in DESC order. You're using some different syntax then me but it seems like this is what you're looking for.

```
arel  = Post.arel_table
query = arel.project(Arel.select('*'))
query.order(arel[:published_at].desc).to_sql
```

This is the best guess I have for what you're trying to do.

Comment: What you are describing is a normal `SELECT … FROM … ORDER BY` while my question was about using `ORDER BY` inside an aggregate function.